# Ant checksum comparison?

Tags: ant, conditional-statements, checksum

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this code is failing, when the echo debug output clearly shows that the checksums do, in fact, match:

```
<macrodef name="compare">
<attribute name="getChecksumFor"/>
<attribute name="getChecksumFrom"/>
  <sequential>
    <checksum file="@{getChecksumFor}" property="md5.for"/>
    <loadfile srcfile="@{getChecksumFrom}" property="md5.from"/>
    <fail message="WARNING:  Checksums do not match:
    installed FILE=@{getChecksumFor}
    installed FILE=${md5.for}
     required FILE=${md5.from}">
      <condition>
        <not>
          <equals arg1="${md5.from}" arg2="${md5.for}"/>
        </not>
      </condition>
    </fail>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

What's the deal ?  Why is the comparison between arg1 & arg2 failing when they match ?

And what is the "standard way" in Apache Ant to do checksum comparisons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you check the output file of the [checksum task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html), you'll notice that there's a newline character at the end, which is why the comparison is always failing, even when the hashes are the same.

To fix this issue, you'll need to use a [filterchain](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) with `<striplinebreaks/>` when you [loadfile](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html):

```
<macrodef name="compare">
<attribute name="getChecksumFor"/>
<attribute name="getChecksumFrom"/>
  <sequential>
    <checksum file="@{getChecksumFor}" property="md5.for"/>
    <loadfile srcfile="@{getChecksumFrom}" property="md5.from">
      <filterchain>
        <striplinebreaks/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <fail message="WARNING:  Checksums do not match:
    installed FILE=@{getChecksumFor}
    installed FILE=${md5.for}
     required FILE=${md5.from}">
      <condition>
        <not>
          <equals arg1="${md5.from}" arg2="${md5.for}"/>
        </not>
      </condition>
    </fail>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

The glaring issue with this approach is that this [macrodef](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) `<compare>` can only be used once, because the properties `md5.for` & `md5.from` can only be set once.  Run your file with the `ant -v` option for verbose mode, and you'll see the warning:

> Override ignored for property "md5.for"

One possible fix is to use ant-contrib to unset any properties right before you set them.  Or, if you're using Ant version 1.8.0+, then you can define [local](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) properties.

Here's another approach:

```
<macrodef name="compare">
<attribute name="getChecksumFor"/>
<sequential>
  <fail message="WARNING: Incorrect checksum for @{getChecksumFor}">
    <condition>
      <not>
        <checksum>
          <fileset file="@{getChecksumFor}"/>
        </checksum>
      </not>
    </condition>
  </fail>
</sequential>
</macrodef>
```

This will calculate the checksum for "file1.ext" (for example), and compare it against the corresponding "file1.ext.MD5" file:  This works because the [Checksum class](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/master/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Checksum.java#L59) implements the [Condition interface](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/b690788b10b73a5a963fb3a72d1749916139cfd2/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/condition/Condition.java#L27-L33), which will return a boolean value.  Tested & working!!!

So, how do you perform the comparison if the file & MD5 file are stored in different directories ?  I'm not sure what the correct "ant way" is, but a quick & dirty solution would be to [copy](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) them both to some [temporary location](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mkdir.html), pass them into the macro, then [delete](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) them, like this:

```
<target name="init">
  <mkdir dir="${temp}"/>
</target>

<target name="check1" depends="init">
  <copy file="${dir1}/${file1.ext}" todir="${temp}" overwrite="true"/>
  <copy file="${dir2}/${file1.ext}.MD5" todir="${temp}" overwrite="true"/>
  <compare getChecksumFor="${temp}/${file1.ext}"/>
  <delete file="${temp}/${file1.ext}"/>
  <delete file="${temp}/${file1.ext}.MD5"/>
  <delete dir="${temp}"/>
</target>

<target name="target1" depends="check1">
  <!-- check1 passed:  Safe to proceed -->
</target>
```

The problem here, is that I have designed this to fail fast, which means that if it does fail, the deletions on the temporary files will never be performed:  But luckily for me, this `${temp}` directory is already part of my cleanup task.

```
<target name="clean">
  <delete dir="${temp}"/>
</target>
```

Here's an alternate solution where the macro will assume the job of copying the files to the same directory:

```
<macrodef name="compare">
<attribute name="getChecksumFor"/>
<attribute name="getChecksumFrom"/>
<sequential>
  <delete dir="${temp}/checksums"/>
  <mkdir dir="${temp}/checksums"/>
  <copy file="@{getChecksumFor}" todir="${temp}/checksums" overwrite="true"/>
  <copy file="@{getChecksumFrom}" todir="${temp}/checksums" overwrite="true"/>
  <fail message="WARNING: Incorrect checksum for @{getChecksumFor}">
    <condition>
      <not>
        <checksum>
          <fileset dir="${temp}/checksums">
            <exclude name="*.MD5"/>
          </fileset>
        </checksum>
      </not>
    </condition>
  </fail>
  <delete dir="${temp}/checksums"/>
</sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: You can localise properties inside macros, see: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html

Comment: @martinclayton ...Thanks!  I'm not sure what your preferred way is ?  But with local, I will be able to add more information to the fail message!!! ...Altho, honestly, I wasn't even aware of the method prior to 1.8.0:  property="parent.@{file}" & dir="${parent.@{file}}"